# API for live traffic information in the form of JSON or Text or other formate

Tags: traffic

i want to get any google api which can give me live traffic information between two locations in the form of text or JSON which i can store in my database and can also generate alerts about traffic that if traffic is going good or have any jam or busy traffic

i am trying to find it but could not find any appropriate solution for this